# Combine switch statement with a for loop

Tags: java, user-interface, switch-statement

Im currently working on a java GUI. Now my question is, how to combine a switch statement  with a for loop in a proper way. The current way is working, but it requires a lot of time to type the statement.

```
public void labelSwitchCase(int i, int userInput) {
    // switch case on i
    switch (i) {

        case 0:  gridLabels[i].setText("" + userInput);
        break;

        case 1: gridLabels[i].setText("" + userInput);
        break;  

        case 2: gridLabels[i].setText("" + userInput);
        break;  

        case 3: gridLabels[i].setText("" + userInput);
        break;  

        case 4: gridLabels[i].setText("" + userInput);
        break;  

        case 5: gridLabels[i].setText("" + userInput);
        break;  

        case 6: gridLabels[i].setText("" + userInput);
        break;      

        case 7: gridLabels[i].setText("" + userInput);
        break;      

        case 8: gridLabels[i].setText("" + userInput);
        break;      
        // no defoult               
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the point of this switch statement? You're doing always the same thing in each case.

Comment: What is  "the current way", and what's wrong with it? All you've shown is a switch which does the same thing on cases 0-8. (And which could be rewritten more simply if that's your intent.)

Comment: Sounds like an example of the [For-Case Paradigm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-switch_sequence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use:

```
public void labelSwitchCase(int i, int userInput) {
    gridLabels[i].setText("" + userInput);     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this (note the String.valueof):

```
public void labelSwitchCase(
    final int index,
    final int userinput)
{
    gridLables[index].setText(String.valueOf(userInput));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method should be :

```
public void labelSwitchCase(int i, int userInput) {
    gridLabels[i].setText("" + userInput);
}
```

No `for` loop needed.

Answer (score 0):

In all of the switch conditions, you are doing same thing..

```
gridLabels[i].setText("" + userInput);
```

So, you don't have to have switch statement for all cases.

You can simply just set text inside your function as

```
public void labelSwitchCase(int i, int userInput) 
{     
gridLabels[i].setText("" + userInput);   
}
```